# PHP Mysql Ajax - dynamic dropdown did not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dynamic, dropdown

I tried to make a dynamic dropdown, when choosing any poly option in the doctor dropdown the same doctor always appears.

**This is the code for dynamic dropdown**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Poly : </label>
            <select name="poly" id="poly" class="form-control" style="width: 50%">
                <option disabled selected>--Choose Poly--</option>
                <?php
                $sqql = mysqli_query($kon,"SELECT * FROM poly") or die(mysqli_error($kon));
                while ($rorow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqql)) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php $rorow['id_poly'];?>"><?php echo $rorow['poly']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Doctor : </label>
            <select name="doctor" id="doctor" class="form-control" style="width: 50%">
                <option disabled selected>--Choose doctor--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

**this is code for ajax**

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#poly").change(function(){
            var id_poly = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"getdoctor.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: {id_poly:id_poly},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $("#doctor").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**this code for getdoctor.php**

```
    $ouput ='';
$dok = mysqli_query($kon,"SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE id_poly = '".isset($_POST["id_poly"])."'") or die(mysqli_error($kon));

$output .= '<option value="" disabled selected>--Choose doctor--</option>';
if (mysqli_num_rows($dok)>0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dok)) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id_doctor"].'">'.$row["doctor"].'</option>';

    }
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: @mickmackusa I copied the query from another code and forgot to delete die()

Comment: yes i have a doctor with id_poly

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to check your submitted value and inject it into the query in the same step.

`isset()` is a reasonable check to execute before building your query to avoid a `Notice`, but it will only deliver `true` or `false`.  This is fouling up your intended query.  [See what happens.](https://3v4l.org/u5KIT)

Sending back html is not as clean as processing a json object in a loop to generate the new html.

Here is my untested suggested code:

PHP:

```
// connect with $kon
$result[] = ["", "--Choose doctor--"];
if (isset($_POST["id_poly"])) {
    if ($dok = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT id_doctor, doctor FROM doctor WHERE id_poly = " . (int)$_POST["id_poly"]))
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dok)) {
            $result[] = [$row["id_doctor"], $row["doctor"]];
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then back in your `success` function:

```
var doctor = $("#doctor");
doctor.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    doctor.append('<option value="' + data[i][0] + '"' + (i ? "" : " disabled") + '>' + data[i][1] + '</option>');
}
```

`(i ? "" : " disabled")` <-- this is a zero / non-zero check, so that only the first option is `disabled`.

Comment: Be more descriptive with why it doesn't work for you.  What errors are you seeing in your client-side and server-side logs?

Comment: Remember, I can't see your screen.  I don't know what is in your database table.  I don't know what `$_POST` values you are submitting.  I don't see the errors.  I don't know if your connection is live.

Comment: no error, only the second dropdown doesn't show anything

Comment: Sending raw html isn't really the cleanest way to perform this process.  On StackOverflow, you will find tens of examples of how to conduct the `<option>` replacement task by passing a json object back from the php script and running a javascript loop to generate the new list of options.

Comment: @tifa Okay, I've extended (but not tested) my advice.  Please give this code a try.  If it doesn't work, please express the errors that are revealed in your server-side error logs and your client-side console.log.